# pytesseract Output is not defined

Tags: python, ubuntu, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

Trying to run tesseract on python, this is my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pytesseract
import Image
# def main():
jpgCounter = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/manel/Desktop/fotografias etiquetas'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        jpgCounter += 1

for i in range(1, 2):

    name                = str(i) + ".jpg"
    nameBW              = str(i) + "_bw.jpg"
    img                 = cv2.imread(name,0) #zero -> abre em grayscale
    # img                 = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    kernel = np.array([[0,-1,0], [-1,5,-1], [0,-1,0]])
    img = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
    cv2.normalize(img,img,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    med                 = np.median(img)



    retval, threshold_manual    = cv2.threshold(img, med*0.6, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(threshold_manual, lang='eng', config='-psm 11', nice=0, output_type=Output.STRING))
```

the error im getting is the following:

> NameError: name 'Output' is not defined

Any idea why I'm getting this?
thank you!

Comment: Try writing `pytesseract.Output.STRING`.

Comment: @VasilisG.  
 
corrected to this: output_type=pytesseract.Output.STRING got this(different error! ): AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Output'

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/pytesseract.py#L163) of `pytesseract`, `output_type` has a default value of `Output.STRING`, so you can omit that argument, as well as the `nice` argument in your case.

Comment: @VasilisG. thank you for your suggestion. the problem is that im getting a different error when i do so.

AttributeError: 

  File "img_proce_clean2.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(threshold_manual, config='-psm 11'))
  File "/home/manel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 104, in image_to_string
    if len(image.split()) == 4:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you have installed [original pytesseract package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract) (downloaded using pip) and referring documentation of [madmaze GitHub version](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract), actually both are different.

**I suggest uninstalling the present version and cloning the GitHub repo and installing the same, by following this steps:**

1. Uninstall present version:

   `pip uninstall pytesseract`
2. Clone [madmaze/pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) GitHub repo by either using git:

   `git clone https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract.git`

   or download it directly by clicking [here](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/archive/master.zip)
3. Get to the root directory of the cloned repo and run:

   `pip install .`

Answer (score 12):

Add.

```
from pytesseract import Output
```

Comment: This is a better approach over uninstalling and then installing from source.